# Fast and reliable network transfer on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, backup, rsync

I have had to do a significant number of filesystem backups and other large file transfers between Linux machines over the internet lately, and the overall experience with the default tools has been nothing short of disappointing.

The ISP on one end suffers from periodic short interruptions of service, which are for the most part unnoticeable. That is except for SSH, which just drops the connection and whatever data stream was being transferred thru it. This of course makes BTRFS backups of any sizable subvolume virtually impossible, as there is at the moment no official support for resuming an interrupted send/receive.

Rsync transfer isn't much better, not only dropping the file transfer backup at the first connection problem, but also having a significant per-file overhead and delivering at its peak only ~50% of the max bandwidth.

There are of course some ways around these issues like restarting with --partial and using GNU parallel to saturate the bandwidth, but having to check and manually restart failed backups throws automation out of the window. Plus writing scripts to compensate for the missing features not just error-prone and time-consuming, but in the end it is a temporary solution to a permanent problem, one which shouldn't exist to begin with.

On the other hand I have been using MOSH to keep terminals alive and autossh/systemd services to keep SSH tunnels open between machines, so at least superficially it looks like there should be some tool or tools for file transfer that:

1. Abstract a stable tunnel over an unstable network.
2. Can pause the stream in case of network shenanigans (or even at user's will) and resume the transfer as soon as the server/network are back online.
3. Uses the entire network bandwidth when available.

All of these are commonplace in browsers and P2P programs. I don't think backing up a few Tb of data should feel like rocket science in this day and age. Network hiccups not only aren't rare, but they're almost guaranteed to happen during the span of a day.

What's a good tool / pipeline to transfer large volumes of data between *nix systems over the internet that's resilient enough to network errors so as to be left running unattended until completion?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @squillman What's a good tool / pipeline to transfer large volumes of data between *nix systems over the internet that's resilient enough to network errors so as to be left running unattended until completion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with unreliable networks (as many of us do) you need to build a reliable transfer mechanism on top of your network.

1. UDP-based VPN. For example, OpenVPN can be configured as a peer-to-peer transport that is resilient even to changes of IP address.

   To maintain efficiency you can run this with no encryption and rely on the `rsync/ssh` transport layer providing encryption. Or (better) you can invert this and let your VPN layer provide the encryption and then run `rsync` over as simple a transport as possible - `ssh` with a null cipher, or using an `rsync` daemon on the server side, both which offer no encryption at all. (There's no harm using VPN encryption *and* `ssh` transport encryption other than the added processing and potential corresponding reduction in throughput.)
2. Keep `rsync` over `ssh` but use the `retry` command to repeat the attempt multiple times:

   ```
   retry rsync -av --partial remoteHost:/path/to/source /path/to/target
   ```

   There are various options for `retry` that allow you to provide alternative exit conditions (`--times 5`, for example). See `man retry` for details.

Professionally, I've used both approaches depending on the situation.

Note that `rsync` is not necessarily the fastest way to transfer a large data set across a WAN link. It's relatively computationally expensive and trades this by design against an expected slow network connection. As data links increase in speed the benefits offered by `rsync` can reduce - at least until you have a "mostly unchanged" dataset to update.